# Unable to install any ruby versions using RVM in macOS Mojave 10.14.2

Tags: openssl, ruby, homebrew, rvm, macos-mojave

After upgrading to Mojave 10.14.2 I tried to install any ruby versions using RVM.

I get the following error message related to OpenSSL.

I have latest command line tools (Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.1) and Xcode installed.

`rvm install 2.5.1
Warning, new version of rvm available '1.29.7', you are using older version '1.29.6'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
ruby-2.5.1 - #removing src/ruby-2.5.1..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.14/x86_64/ruby-2.5.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/macuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.5.1 - #downloading ruby-2.5.1, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.5.1 - #extracting ruby-2.5.1 to /Users/macuser/.rvm/src/ruby-2.5.1.....
ruby-2.5.1 - #applying patch /Users/macuser/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.5.1/libressl_2_7.patch.
ruby-2.5.1 - #configuring.........................
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/macuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
please read /Users/macuser/.rvm/log/1546514340_ruby-2.5.1/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.`

Got the following message in configure.log:

`checking size of long long... configure: error: in /Users/macuser/.rvm/src/ruby-2.5.1':
configure: error: cannot compute sizeof (long long)
See config.log' for more details`

Answer (score 0):

This is crazy. Nothing I have tried works, except moving `/usr/local/include/` out of the way. Ymmv.